# Styling unordered horizontal list with ...best possible way

Tags: html, css, xhtml, html-lists

To make lists horizontal and hide default bullets, is it necessary to give `{display:inline}` and `{float:left}` both to the `<li>` tags or anyone of these alone is enough?

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">First item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">item 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Last item</a></li>
</ul>
```

How to make cross browser (including IE6 and FF2) , pixel perfect horizontal list without bullet in best way?

What is best and short method?

```
ul {}
li {}
a  {}
```

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson - my previous question title was better. "Styling HTML list-items…" is not refering ,what i'm asking.

Comment: @Jitendra: Your previous title is too verbose. Your question is regarding the styling of HTML lists.

Comment: but IMO question is not just about the styling of list item  it's a question of use of {display:inline} and {float:left}, and about ur revised title "Styling HTML list-items…" my question is only related to horizontal unordered list, not about vertial list and ordered list. "Styling HTML list-items…" cover all things , which is not the aim of my question

Comment: You don't include the specifics in the title, you put those in the body. Titles should be short, and express brevity.

Comment: @Jonathan Exactly, but he doesn't understand that, I explained it to him before too.

Comment: @Jonathan @Nimbuz - maybe u both are right but "Styling HTML list-items…"  title looks like I'm asking how to style list in HTML, which is not the aim of my question. and title should give hint of the question. as u both are saying every question related to style of list item in HTML would be "Styling HTML list-items…". Would you like same tile in multiple questions. I'm not saying your are wrong.

Comment: @Jitendra: "Pixel Perfect," "Cross Browser," and "with link" are all noise. Other than that, the title would be good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, either one alone is enough. You could even use `inline-block` if you like, although it doesn't have very good support in FF2. Hiding bullets is done with `list-style:none;`

You could setup a simple test quickly to check these:

```
#one, #two, #three { list-style:none }
#one li            { float:left }
#two li            { display:inline }
#three li          { display:inline-block }
```

```
<ul id="one">
  <li>Float left</li> 
  <li>In this example</li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<ul id="two">
  <li>Display inline</li>
  <li>In this example</li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<ul id="three">
  <li>Inline-block</li>
  <li>In this example</li>
</ul>
```

See how they render: http://jsbin.com/opiqu3/

Comment: to make list horizontal in all browser {display:inline} is enough

Comment: Is that a statement, or a question? My first sentence ("...either one alone is enough") states the same thing.

Comment: I don't see where my post disagrees with Sarfraz's post. Mine preceded his by a minute - so I don't see the contention.

Comment: u said ("...either one alone is enough") and sarfraz said "display:inline is not necessary but float:left is necessary"

Comment: @Jitendra: Setup a small list, and try it.

Comment: Which method is better to follow? although if we use {display:inline} or { display:inline-block }then don't need to define { list-style:none }

Comment: and { display:inline-block } doesn't have all browser support. and is the  li { display:inline-block } and  li {display:inline} a {display:block} will create same effect?

Comment: @Jitendra: You're talking about a difference in about a dozen chars. It doesn't matter. Just pick one, and continue with development :)

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson - I run a small web design classes and I have to explain to students which method they should used to make list horizontal

Comment: @Jitendra: I've taught a web-design class as well, and I would have no problem telling my students, "It really doesn't matter." :)

Answer (score 0):

`display:inline` is not necessary but `float:left` is necessary to make it horizontal and like you said about hiding default bullets, then even `list-style:none` is also necessary.

Comment: but if we use {display:inline} then it align item horizontally as well as hide the bullets without {list-style:none}